# React array did not update despite using useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add an element into an array after I click the "click me" button.
I did a console log to make sure it went inside the function, but despite the function being call, nothing changes.

I also try using useEffect to check if my variable got update

Relevant code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  let [test, setTest] = useState(["1", "2", "3"]);

  const onChange = () => {
    console.log("onChange");
    test.unshift("4");
  };

  const cards = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        {test.map((item, i) => (
          <ul key={i}>
            <li>{item}</li>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("cardData ", test);
  }, [test]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => onChange()}>Click me</button>
      {cards()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Really need some advice on where did i go wrong

This is my codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-water-1r4gh?file=/src/App.js:303-307)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you directly mutate the `test` (test.unshift does mutate the `test` instance) and rendering does not happen since no reference change was detected (**shallow reference** is used when rendering happens).

Try this

```
  const onChange = () => {
    console.log("onChange");

    const testCopy = [...test];
    testCopy.unshift("4");
    setTest(testCopy);
  };
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-wildflower-lkf4u?file=/src/App.js:160-302

Another **NOT** working case can be given like below due to using the same instance reference (`test`).

```
  const onChange = () => {
    console.log("onChange");
    test.unshift("4");
    setTest(test);
  };
```

Comment: @yongchang, can you please mark this as the answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `setTest` function, which is the only thing you should be using to mutate the array `test`. Set the new value using `setTest` and you should be fine.

Comment: i did....click on the same link on my question. i have call the setTest and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your code

1. you are mutating the state with `test.unshift`
2. you do not use the `setTest`

try

```
  const onChange = () => {
    console.log("onChange");
    const updatedTest = [...test];
    updatedTest.unshift("4");
    setTest(updatedTest);
  };
```

Comment: @giorgimoniava fair point, updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You are altering the state `test` directly without using `setTest` .

*Mutating the state directly breaks the primary principle of React's unidirectional data flow, making your app fragile and basically ignoring the whole component lifecycle.*

Upgrade your `onChange` function as:

```
  const onChange = () => {
    console.log("onChange");
    setTest([...test, "4"]);
  };
```

Check [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-borg-nxso2?file=/src/App.js:523-711).

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are directly mutating the state, you need to use the useState function hook to update the value of a state variable.

here is my solution
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-perlman-436el?file=/src/App.js:0-727

```
export default function App() {
  let [test, setTest] = useState(["1", "2", "3"]);

  const onChange = () => {
    console.log("onChange");
    setTest(["4", ...test]);
  };

  const cards = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        {test.map((item, i) => (
          <ul key={i}>
            <li>{item}</li>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("cardData ", test);
  }, [test]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => onChange()}>Click me</button>
      {cards()}
    </div>
  );
}
```